# Exclude posts from certain category breaks custom pagination

Tags: categories, pagination

I want to show only posts from certain categories so that I exclude them in my `WP_Query()` query. Doing this my custom pagination is not working correctly. Clicking on each one of the number in the pagination itself still shows the same posts.

My Custom pagination:

```
function glean_numeric_posts_nav() {

  if( is_singular() )
    return;

  global $wp_query;

  /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
  if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
  $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

  /** Add current page to the array */
  if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

  /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
  if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
  }

  if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
  }

  echo '<ul class="pagination">' . "\n";

  /** Previous Post Link */
  if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('&laquo;') );

  /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
  if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
      echo '<li>…</li>';
  }

  /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
  sort( $links );
  foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
  }

  /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
  if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
      echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
  }

  /** Next Post Link */
  if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('&raquo;') );

  echo '</ul>' . "\n";

}
```

And in my blog page, I filter those posts by using

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('cat=-10');
```

And then loop them. And next after the loop, I call the `glean_numeric_posts_nav()` function.

Comment: Have you tried previous_post_link as this enables you to use the excluded_terms parameter http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link

Comment: No, I am asked to make changes to the code written by other people. This function is already written and used. Is there any option we could hack into that function to make it work properly?

Comment: Try changing get_previous_posts_link to previous_post_link

Comment: And the same for get_next_posts_link? ok i'll do it for now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to duplicate every instance of `$wp_query` and change it to `$the_query`. Example

```
global $wp_query, $the_query;

  /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
  if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 || $the_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
     return;
```

**EDIT**

Here is the pagination function that I use. Have no time to code now or to really dig into your code. Change accordingly. `$cat_query` and `$cpt_query` are my variables that I use for my custom queries

```
function pietergoosen_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {   
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query, $cat_query, $cpt_query;
        if(is_page_template( 'page-pop.php' )) {
            $pages = $cat_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }elseif(is_page_template( 'page-cpt.php' )) {
            $pages = $cpt_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }else{
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }   
    }   

    if(1 != $pages) {
        $string = _x( 'Page %1$s of %2$s' , '%1$s = current page, %2$s = all pages' , 'pietergoosen' );
        echo "<div class='pagination'><span>" . sprintf( $string, $paged, $pages ) . "</span>";
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>" . __( '&laquo; First', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
        if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>" . __( '&lsaquo; Previous', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";

        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
            }
        }

        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>" . __( 'Next &rsaquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>" . __( 'Last &raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . "</a>";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: So its breaking because it continues to execute after the 1st page even if there's only one page?

Comment: I have made the above change but the pagination buttons dispappear

Comment: Did you change **all** instances. The code I gave you is not complete. Look for all instances modify accordingly. Please turn debug on and check what errors you get

Comment: How could I apply to this declaration? `$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );`

Comment: Any luck with the code I gave you?